# MYSQL and SQLite

Tags: android

I know this might seem like a basic question but can an android app which i know uses SQLite work with a web site like http://www.freemysql.net/client/. I have developed a desktop program in netbeans that functions with this website using MYSQL and I want my android app to upload information to this site as well. Or can i use MYSQL with android. I just need to be pointed in the right direction. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'd recommend adding web service to your website that will allow data to be posted/read through JSON or XML, etc.  This is a "better practice" than trying to access MySQL from Android even if it is possible.

Comment: Its not my website it just hosts my MYSQL Database. To be honest man im a newbie and am familar with MYSQL and just did a few tutorials in SQLite. So i would like to stay would the two just for the moment if its at all even possible regardless of it being bad practice. Thaanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

If you only expect your app to work if "online" you may be able to make it work.  I would expect that the cloud db API already qualifies as a web service interface like Kevin mentioned you would need.  If you want a desktop and Android app to use this same database, it seems vaguely reasonable.

I didn't see any API documentation for the site you mentioned.  I would focus your attention on how to write an Android app that communicates with a web service.  Since you've already written a Java desktop client, you probably already have some idea about this.

If you decide at some point you need access to a database "offline" you should just look at a tutorial for database access on Android.  It's not that painful.  You may want this so you can store data locally and push to the cloud when you're connected.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db